# How to convert TWB file into TWBx file?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I wanted to open my TWB file. However, while opening the file from Tableau desktop it's giving me an error as I need to upgrade to a professional package, so is there any way I can do this without taking the premium version.

I tried online convertor but none of them is working.